# Would "temporal proximity" be an effective way to label the axis of a graph?

Tags: phrase-requests, formality

I have a bunch of events that vary in duration and also vary in how recently they occurred.  I want to graph these events so that they look like a typical bar graph, with all the bases resting on the X axis and the Y axis representing time.  This way it will be easy to see which events lasted longer than other events (the taller the bar, the longer the duration of the event).  But I also want to express how far in the past each event took place.  More recent events would be closer to the origin than the ones further back in history.

I think "duration" is a good label for the Y axis, with "hours" being the unit of measure.  As for the X axis, I'm having a harder time deciding on a way to describe the property that it will represent.  The units of measure will be "days", but I want a word or short phrase to use on the X axis similar to the way "duration" characterizes the Y axis.  The best I could come up with is "temporal proximity".

Does this work, or is it going to sound stilted, contrived, pedantic... etc.?

Comment: What numbers/labels are you putting on the x axis exactly?

Comment: @ Killing Time thanks for the help editing, I think it makes a definite improvement.  I should have put more time and effort into writing my question.  I guess I still need to do more work in developing mindfulness.

Comment: I might use "Date of Event" on the X axis.

Comment: @ Laurel  The Y axis will use hours for the units, and the word "duration" as the label.  The X axis will be measured in days (or perhaps weeks), but I'm not sure if "temporal proximity" is going to look goofy as a label.  I'm open to any suggestions.

Comment: @ Greybeard  That might have a lower risk for embarrassment, but I'm thinking that it might be adding complexity.  I think I would be figuring out the difference in days between any two given dates.  Also I don't have really precise measurements or exact dates, as this is just an aid in getting an idea of what went into some projects/repairs I've had a hand in doing over the summer.  It's somewhere between an analytic tool and a mild form of amusement and also a way to see if going too far with my word-a-day calendar!  :)

Comment: I can't say whether it's good or bad ... but I can say I've used it

Comment: That said, temporal proximity is more useful when you're comparing nearness of events to each other, as opposed to a single set point. In that case _recency_ or _days since_ is better

Comment: Won't the dependent and independent variables conflict? _This started two hours ago and lasted three h...._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a problem with "temporal proximity", but *recency* would make sense to me.  However, [this dictionary definition](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/recency) only gives a qualitative rather than a quantitative definition.  On the other hand, the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/recency) gives

> the fact of being recent, **or the degree to which something is recent**

(emphasis added). (If I were making this graph I might add "(days since event)" as a subtitle ...)

However, if we're being really picky and you're plotting the x-axis in terms of increasing "days since event", then you should consider *temporal distance* rather than proximity — and  I can't think of a good substitute for "not-recency" ...

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not an effective label. It does sound stilted and contrived, but worse than that it's unclear what it means. Ideally you want figures to be as self-contained and self-explanatory as possible. As a reader, "temporal proximity" would annoy me because I would have to look away from the figure and hunt in the caption or text to figure what it meant.

Personally, I would write something like "Days since event". This sounds more natural and is much easier to interpret than "temporal proximity."

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered ***age*** or a variant like "*age(days)*" or "*age in days*"?

M-W:

> ***[age](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/age)*** *noun*
> **1 c**: the length of an existence extending from the beginning to any given time